# How to Debug Java Web Application which is running on JBoss Server on Local Machine in Eclipse Environment

Tags: java, jboss

I joined a project which has been already developed and its an Web Application deployed on JBoss Server.  I have configured the Web Application on my local JBoss Server and it is running fine. I want to start debugging the Application but I am not sure where to start from and how to debug an Java Web Application from Eclipse and so my question is  Q: How to Debug Java Web Application which is running on JBoss Server on Local Machine in Eclipse Environment {Pointers to useful resources or other steps would be highly appreciated}?